# Prevent WebView Audio from Timing Out When Screen Off

Tags: java, android

My Android app features a WebView that plays consecutive audio tracks. As long as the screen stays on, the audio will play endlessly as desired. However, if the device screen is off, the audio stops playing after just a few minutes. Is it possible to prevent Android from killing the audio playback even when the screen is off?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a [Background Service](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service) for that music then your music will not stop.